# How do i create a menu where the user can insert and delete think he/she add? in eclipse javascript google-appengine

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse

```
this is my servlet: 
public class Tesina {

private UserService us;
private DatastoreService ds;
public Tesina(){
    us = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
}   

public void add(String data, String nome, String desc) {
    
        Entity e = new Entity(nome);
        e.setProperty("nome", nome);
        e.setProperty("data", data);   
        e.setProperty("desc", desc);
        ds.put(e);
        
        
        }


public String list() {
    
        Query q = new Query();
        PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);
        List<Entity> list = pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(100));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        
        for(Entity e: list) {
            sb.append("<table>");
            sb.append("<tr><td style=\"border: 1px solid transparent; padding-top:10px;\" id=\"cena\">");
            sb.append("<p class=\"bg-success\">"+e.getProperty("data")+"</p>");
            sb.append("<h4>"+e.getProperty("nome")+"</h4>"+e.getProperty("desc")+"</td></tr>");
            sb.append("</table>");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }


}
```

i dont know how to create a delete method, the user might add and delete item on the list.
the user might olso be able to add ad img file.

i create this code for add events on a news page, thet people can visit but only the admin (me) can modify the list of news.

thanks for the help,  and sorry for the linguage and the layout, this is my first question on Stack overflow.

Comment: when do you want this changes to happen?
will this add and deletes be already sent to the server when you want to add or delete again, or is this only a frontend behavior and then it'll be committed when iti is final?